# regexp replacement depending on matched value

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible WITH A SINGLE REGEXP to execute a different replacement depending on the matched value?

For example, given the string "aaa bbb ccc aaa ddd" I would like to replace each occurrence of "aaa" with "alpha", "bbb" with "beta", "ccc" with "gamma" and "ddd" with "delta".

Very easy to do with four separate regexp replacements, I know:

```
my $s = "aaa bbb ccc aaa ddd";
$s =~ s/aaa/alpha/g;
$s =~ s/bbb/betaa/g;
$s =~ s/ccc/gamma/g;
$s =~ s/ddd/delta/g;
```

The question is whether that is possible to do the same with just one statement like:

```
$s =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
```

If that matters, I'm using perl.

This is just a simplified example for a more complex problem I'm trying to solve; please do not start arguing that I'm asking the wrong question and that I should do it differently... if you really believe so, please just ignore the question.

Comment: I don't think so. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that could serve is the [`/e` modifier to `s///`,](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer) which means the right side is interpreted as code, and the matched text is replaced with the value returned by this code.

For your example, you would want something like:

```
$s =~ s/aaa|bbb|ccc/ $& eq 'aaa' ? 'alpha' : $& eq 'bbb' ? 'beta' : 'gamma' /eg;
```

Or better (as there is a performance penalty associated to using `$&`):

```
$s =~ s/(aaa|bbb|ccc)/ $1 eq 'aaa' ? 'alpha' : $1 eq 'bbb' ? 'beta' : 'gamma' /eg;
```

By the way, you may also want to use different separators and the `/x` modifier to improve readability if your expressions become really big. Example:

```
$s =~ s
        { ( aaa | bbb | ccc ) }
        {
            $1 eq 'aaa'
                ? 'alpha'
                : $1 eq 'bbb'
                    ? 'beta'
                    : 'gamma'
        }egx;
```

---

### Edit: Quality

I proposed this answer because the question asked for a replacement depending on the matched value, but didn't specify whether, in their actual problem (as opposed to the simplified version they showed), the test on the match value would be a simple equality test.

A point was raised that a solution based on `/e` is of lesser quality than one based on a hash. This observation is valid, up to a point. In my opinion, the two factors of quality on which the solutions differ are:

- Legibility: The hash solution is an unquestionable winner on this point.
- Resource usage: On the example proposed by the OP, the `/e` solution wins on both time and space usage¹. In case the problem becomes bigger, the two solutions will scale differently: the `/e` solution will be linear in time and constant in space, whereas the hash solution will be (roughly) constant in time and linear in space.

---

1. Locally, `/e` is 5–10% faster, and `%replacement` uses 588 bytes of memory. The benchmark code is:

   my $str         = 'aaa bbb ccc aaa ddd';
   my $pattern     = qr{ ( aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd ) }x;
   my %replacement = ( "aaa" => "alpha", "bbb" => "beta", "ccc" => "gamma", "ddd" => "delta", );
   cmpthese( 10000000,
       {
           e => sub { my $s = $str; $s =~ s/$pattern/$1 eq 'aaa' ? 'alpha' : $1 eq 'bbb' ? 'beta': $1 eq 'c'? 'gamma': 'delta'/eg },
           h => sub { my $s = $str; $s =~ s/$pattern/$replacement{$1}/ge; },
       }
   );

Comment: A hash is a *far* better mechanism to use here by almost any measure than a long string of conditional operators.

Answer (score 4):

You can use hash to replace matches with desired values,

```
my %replacement = (
    "aaa" => "alpha",
    "bbb" => "beta", 
    "ccc" => "gamma",
    "ddd" => "delta",
);
my ($pattern) = map qr/$_/, join "|", map quotemeta, keys %replacement;

$s =~ s/($pattern)/$replacement{$1}/ge;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. What would $pattern and $replacement be in your statement?

Comment: You should use `my $pattern = join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %changes` to make sure that a match for, say, `aabbcc` is found before `aa`.